# Touchscreen after sleep not working

Tags: touchscreen

i've recently installed eOS on my Primebok 13 (with Touchscreen) and had some bugs. When send the nb to sleep and resume it, touchscreen will not work after resume. Touchscreen will work after a restart. I had to install touchpad and touchscreen drivers manualy. is this a known problem and a easy fix available? Thx

Answer (score 0):

it is a specigic driver for this model so i guess it will not work on your yoga. i solved the problem with modprobe script on wakeup folder